# How to programatically update selected value of sui-select element of ng2-semantic for Angular

Tags: angular, ng2-semantic-ui

I want to be able to set the selected value in a sui-select element from my code in the component. See documentation on semantic sui-select element here: https://edcarroll.github.io/ng2-semantic-ui/#/modules/select